# Root (0) user running IMRemoteURL

Tags: macos, root

My system is set to sleep after 3hrs. I was away from my machine for an hour, came back and it was sleeping and had to log back in. I looked at logs to try and figure out why did my machine go to sleep two hours ahead of schedule, and why would actv from Root (0) using IMRemote occur? 
Also, commands in terminal that require password if using sudo or sudo su will not accept my password. I have setup a root user myself and just changed the password and that password will not open the command. I dont now very much about this stuff, all help appreciated.

Comment: Did you intend to tag this IOS?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a Mac. I Googled "IMRemoteURL" and found this [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7903023). It looks like IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent is a process that listens for incoming iMessages and can wake up the computer to display them.

I'm not sure why your computer went to sleep earlier than it is set to, but I don't think it is connected to that proccess.

With your `sudo` problem, are you sure you don't have caps lock on or something? Sorry if that's too obvious, but it's a very common mistake.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I did find the system pref setting that was causing the sleep. And no I did not have caps on.. In fact I have a root setup (as much root as you can get with Apple walling people off from certain system elements) I also in root and in admin in sudo su & su -s still was given a password to run some rather generic terminal commands to gain more info regarding uses etc.. this still as for my password in both root and admin as sudo or sudo su and in both cases the password I use to login to either will not work as the password to run the command.???

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit difficult to understand. Are you saying that when you type `sudo ...`, it asks for your password and your login password doesn't work there?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what im saying. Additionally when signed in as root, I still can not run grep commands for example, as well as some others. When im in as admin running sudo or sudo su or -s I will ask for a password and when i enter the admin password it says wrong pass word. When im in root it does the same. When i go into single user mode, it also will not let me in terminal run those commands.

Comment: Try `su admin` while signed in as admin and `su root` while signed in as root. Does your password work then?